# Problem with MQTT in Flutter, client sending value multiple times but only one value was created

Tags: flutter, dart, mqtt

I hope someone could help me with a problem.

I am new to Flutter and Dart. I usually use c++ and work with Node Red and a bit of Python.

But now I want to create a simple app to control the UI of my IOT system instead of the Node Red dashboard.

Everything is working fine except for a very strange error, which almost makes me despair.

I have built several widgets which are used several times in the code.

I use MQTT to handle the communication between the app and Node Red.

Everything works fine, I can receive data from Node Red and display it in Gauges, for example.

I have chosen the structure of the code so that I have everything to do with MQTT in one place and send the data back and forth between the widgets with streams.

I know it's certainly not professional but I'm learning and so please excuse if it's not the correct way.

The problem I have is that when I want to send a value of a slider via MQTT, the value in Flutter comes only once but it is sent several times via MQTT to Node Red.

If I solve this with an IF query and a variable so that only one message is sent if the new value is different from the old value then it works fine. But now comes the problem. If I then want to send a message that is generated by a function of a button, this only works once, because the value does not change.

Although the message from the slider and the message from the button are sent in different streams and are also processed in two different functions, they seem to interfere with each other.

I just can't find a solution to either transmit the slider value only 1 time or that the 2 functions don't interfere with each other.

Here is the code:

mqtt.dart

```
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_client.dart';
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_server_client.dart';
import 'package:mts_app_canopy/Network/stream_controll.dart';
import 'package:mts_app_canopy/ConfigData/credentials.dart' as credentials;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

typedef OnReceive = Function(Map<String, dynamic> message);

// Class to handle the MQTT connection
class MtsMqtt {
  late MqttServerClient client;
  final String serverId;
  final String clientIDmts;
  final String userId;
  final String userPassword;
  OnReceive onReceive;

  final Map<String, StreamSubscription> _publishStreamSubscriptions = {};
  String? _previousPayload; // Variable for the previous payload

  // Topics for receiving
  static const String mtsCanopyTest = 'mts/canopy/test';
  static const String mtsCanopyTestOne = 'mts/canopy/gaga';
  static const String mtsCanopyMainCb = 'mts/canopy/main/cb';
  static const String mtsCanopyMainKitchside = 'mts/canopy/main/kitchenside';
  static const String mtsCanopyMainStorage = 'mts/canopy/main/storage';
  static const String mtsCanopyMainCanopy = 'mts/canopy/main/canopy';

  // Topics for publishing
  static const String mtsCanopyTestPub = 'dimmersoeze';
  static const String mtsCanopyTestPub2 = 'dimmersoeze2'; // neues Topic
  static const String mtsCanopyTestSwitch = 'mts/canopy/test/switch';

  // Constructor for MtsMqtt
  MtsMqtt({
    required this.serverId,
    required this.clientIDmts,
    required this.userId,
    required this.userPassword,
    required this.onReceive,
  });

  // methode to setup up client and connect to the broker
  void setupAndConnect() async {
    client = MqttServerClient.withPort(serverId, clientIDmts, 1883);
    client.logging(on: false);
    client.keepAlivePeriod = 60;

    client.onDisconnected = () {
      print('Disconnected from the MQTT broker');
    };

    client.onSubscribed = (String topic) {
      print('Successfully subscribed to topic $topic');
    };

    final connMessage = MqttConnectMessage()
        .authenticateAs(userId, userPassword)
        .startClean()
        .withWillQos(MqttQos.atLeastOnce);
    client.connectionMessage = connMessage;

    try {
      await client.connect();
    } catch (e) {
      client.disconnect();
    }

    if (client.connectionStatus!.state == MqttConnectionState.connected) {
      print('Connected to the MQTT broker');
    } else {
      print('Connection failed - disconnecting');
    }

    // Subscribe to the topics
    client.subscribe(mtsCanopyTest, MqttQos.exactlyOnce);
    client.subscribe(mtsCanopyTestOne, MqttQos.exactlyOnce);
    client.subscribe(mtsCanopyMainCanopy, MqttQos.exactlyOnce);
    client.subscribe(mtsCanopyMainCb, MqttQos.exactlyOnce);
    client.subscribe(mtsCanopyMainKitchside, MqttQos.exactlyOnce);
    client.subscribe(mtsCanopyMainStorage, MqttQos.exactlyOnce);

    // Listen to the received messages
    client.updates!.listen(
      (List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage>> c) {
        final MqttPublishMessage recMess = c[0].payload as MqttPublishMessage;
        final String payload =
            MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(recMess.payload.message);

        Map<String, dynamic> messageMap = jsonDecode(payload);
        onReceive(messageMap);
        CustomStreamController.addToStream(mtsCanopyTest, messageMap);
        CustomStreamController.addToStream(mtsCanopyTestOne, messageMap);
        CustomStreamController.addToStream(mtsCanopyMainCanopy, messageMap);
        CustomStreamController.addToStream(mtsCanopyMainCb, messageMap);
        CustomStreamController.addToStream(mtsCanopyMainKitchside, messageMap);
        CustomStreamController.addToStream(mtsCanopyMainStorage, messageMap);
      },
    );

    // Setup the publish streams after connection is successful
    _setupPublishStreams();
  }

  // Setup the publish streams Continuous or Discrete
  void _setupPublishStreams() {
    // //All setups for Continuous
    // //continuous
    _publishStreamSubscriptions[mtsCanopyTestPub] =
        CustomPublishController.getTopicStream(mtsCanopyTestPub)
            .listen((message) {
      _publishMessageContinuous(mtsCanopyTestPub, message);
    });
    //Continuous
    _publishStreamSubscriptions[mtsCanopyTestPub2] =
        CustomPublishController.getTopicStream(mtsCanopyTestPub2)
            .listen((message) {
      _publishMessageContinuous(mtsCanopyTestPub2, message);
    });

    //all setups for Discrete
    //Discrete
    _publishStreamSubscriptions[mtsCanopyTestSwitch] =
        CustomPublishController.getTopicStream(mtsCanopyTestSwitch)
            .listen((message) {
      _publishMessageDiscrete(mtsCanopyTestSwitch, message);
    });
  }

  // Publish to the topics continuouslya
  void _publishMessageContinuous(String topic, Map<String, dynamic> message1) {
    final MqttClientPayloadBuilder builderone = MqttClientPayloadBuilder();
    builderone.addString(jsonEncode(message1));

    // final String payload = jsonEncode(message1);
    // if (payload != _previousPayload) {
    client.publishMessage(topic, MqttQos.atLeastOnce, builderone.payload!);
    // _previousPayload = payload;
    print('Published message: $message1');
    // }
  }

  // Publish to the topics discretely
  void _publishMessageDiscrete(String topic, Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    final MqttClientPayloadBuilder builder = MqttClientPayloadBuilder();
    builder.addString(jsonEncode(message));
    client.publishMessage(topic, MqttQos.atLeastOnce, builder.payload!);
    print('Published message: $message');
  }

  // Disconnect from the MQTT broker
  void disconnect() {
    _publishStreamSubscriptions.forEach((topic, sub) => sub.cancel());
    client.disconnect();
    print('Disconnected from MQTT broker');
  }
}

// Function to setup the MQTT connection
void setupMqttConnection() {
  const String userId = credentials.userId;
  const String userPassword = credentials.userPassword;
  const String serverId = credentials.serverId;
  final String clientIDmts = credentials.clientIDmts;

  final mqttReceived = MtsMqtt(
    serverId: serverId,
    clientIDmts: clientIDmts,
    userId: userId,
    userPassword: userPassword,
    onReceive: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      // Handle received message
    },
  );
  mqttReceived.setupAndConnect();
}
```

here the code for a Slider:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_sliders/sliders.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_core/theme.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:mts_app_canopy/Network/stream_controll.dart';

class DimSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  final String topic;
  final String jsonKey;

  const DimSlider({
    Key? key,
    required this.topic,
    required this.jsonKey,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DimSlider> createState() {
    return _DimSliderState();
  }
}

class _DimSliderState extends State<DimSlider> {
  double _sliderValue = 0.0;
  double _previousSliderValue = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SfSliderTheme(
      data: SfSliderThemeData(
        thumbRadius: 13,
        thumbColor: Colors.blue[800],
        activeTrackColor: Colors.blue[800],
        inactiveTrackColor: Colors.blue[100],
        activeTrackHeight: 10,
        inactiveTrackHeight: 10,
        trackCornerRadius: 5,
        tooltipBackgroundColor: Colors.blue[800],
      ),
      child: SfSlider(
        min: 0.0,
        max: 100.0,
        interval: 1,
        enableTooltip: true,
        tooltipShape: const SfPaddleTooltipShape(),
        numberFormat: NumberFormat('0'),
        tooltipTextFormatterCallback: (actualValue, formattedValue) {
          return '$formattedValue%';
        },
        value: _sliderValue,
        onChanged: (dynamic newValue) {
          final double newSliderValue = newValue as double;
          if (newSliderValue != _previousSliderValue) {
            setState(() {
              _sliderValue = newSliderValue;
              _previousSliderValue = newSliderValue;
            });

            // Erstellen Sie die Nachricht, die an den MQTT Broker gesendet werden soll.
            // Der Schlüssel ist 'widget.jsonKey' und der Wert ist der neue Wert des Sliders.
            Map<String, dynamic> message = {
              widget.jsonKey: mapValue(
                newSliderValue,
                0,
                100,
                0,
                250,
              ).round().toInt(),
            };

            // Fügen Sie die Nachricht zum Stream für das entsprechende Thema hinzu.
            CustomPublishController.addToStream(widget.topic, message);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  // Funktion, die einen Wert von einem Bereich in einen anderen umwandelt
  double mapValue(
    double value,
    double inMin,
    double inMax,
    double outMin,
    double outMax,
  ) {
    double interval = (inMax - inMin) / 15.0;
    int steps = ((value - inMin) / interval).round();
    double stepValue = (outMax - outMin) / 15.0;
    return steps * stepValue + outMin;
  }
}
```

here the stream controller

```
import 'dart:async';

class CustomStreamController {
  static final Map<String, StreamController<Map<String, dynamic>>>
      topicStreams = {};

  static void addToStream(String topic, Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    if (topicStreams.containsKey(topic)) {
      topicStreams[topic]!.add(message);
    }
  }

  static Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> getTopicStream(String topic) {
    if (!topicStreams.containsKey(topic)) {
      topicStreams[topic] = StreamController<Map<String, dynamic>>.broadcast();
    }
    return topicStreams[topic]!.stream;
  }
}

class CustomPublishController {
  static final Map<String, StreamController<Map<String, dynamic>>>
      publishStreams = {};

  static void addToStream(String topic, Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    if (publishStreams.containsKey(topic)) {
      publishStreams[topic]!.add(message);
    }
  }

  static Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> getTopicStream(String topic) {
    if (!publishStreams.containsKey(topic)) {
      publishStreams[topic] =
          StreamController<Map<String, dynamic>>.broadcast();
    }
    return publishStreams[topic]!.stream;
  }

  static void close(String topic) {
    if (publishStreams.containsKey(topic)) {
      publishStreams[topic]!.close();
      publishStreams.remove(topic);
    }
  }
}
```

here a function of a button

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:mts_app_canopy/Network/stream_controll.dart';

class ButtonFunctions {
  static void buttonFunctionJson(String topic, String jsonKey, int value) {
    // Erstellen Sie die Nachricht, die an den MQTT Broker gesendet werden soll.
    Map<String, dynamic> message = {
      jsonKey: jsonEncode({jsonKey: value}),
    };

    CustomPublishController.addToStream(topic, message);
  }

  static void buttonFunctionString(String topic, String stringValue) {
    // Erstellen Sie die Nachricht, die an den MQTT Broker gesendet werden soll.
    Map<String, dynamic> message = {
      stringValue: stringValue,
    };
    CustomPublishController.addToStream(topic, message);
  }
}
```

The problem is here in mqtt.dart

```
// Publish to the topics continuouslya
  void _publishMessageContinuous(String topic, Map<String, dynamic> message1) {
    final MqttClientPayloadBuilder builderone = MqttClientPayloadBuilder();
    builderone.addString(jsonEncode(message1));

    // final String payload = jsonEncode(message1);
    // if (payload != _previousPayload) {
    client.publishMessage(topic, MqttQos.atLeastOnce, builderone.payload!);
    // _previousPayload = payload;
    print('Published message: $message1');
    // }
  }

  // Publish to the topics discretely
  void _publishMessageDiscrete(String topic, Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    final MqttClientPayloadBuilder builder = MqttClientPayloadBuilder();
    builder.addString(jsonEncode(message));
    client.publishMessage(topic, MqttQos.atLeastOnce, builder.payload!);
    print('Published message: $message');
  }
```

If I have the if block commented out like now, the outputs looks like this:

Flutter Debug after hot relaod and use the slider and press the button 3 times:

```
Restarted application in 2’554ms.
I/flutter (32304): Connected to the MQTT broker
I/flutter (32304): Successfully subscribed to topic mts/canopy/test
I/flutter (32304): Successfully subscribed to topic mts/canopy/gaga
I/flutter (32304): Successfully subscribed to topic mts/canopy/main/canopy
I/flutter (32304): Successfully subscribed to topic mts/canopy/main/cb
I/flutter (32304): Successfully subscribed to topic mts/canopy/main/kitchenside
I/flutter (32304): Successfully subscribed to topic mts/canopy/main/storage
I/ViewRootImpl@c2823db[MainActivity](32304): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/flutter (32304): Published message: {val2: 0}
11
I/flutter (32304): Published message: {val2: 17}
11
I/flutter (32304): Published message: {val2: 33}
I/ViewRootImpl@c2823db[MainActivity](32304): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/ViewRootImpl@c2823db[MainActivity](32304): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@c2823db[MainActivity](32304): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/flutter (32304): Published message: {val1: {"val1":1}}
I/ViewRootImpl@c2823db[MainActivity](32304): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@c2823db[MainActivity](32304): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/flutter (32304): Published message: {val1: {"val1":1}}
I/ViewRootImpl@c2823db[MainActivity](32304): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@c2823db[MainActivity](32304): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/flutter (32304): Published message: {val1: {"val1":1}}
```

and in Node Red:

```
dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 0 }
12.7.2023, 09:51:47node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 17 }
12.7.2023, 09:51:48node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 17 }
12.7.2023, 09:51:49node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 17 }
12.7.2023, 09:51:50node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 17 }
12.7.2023, 09:51:51node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 17 }
12.7.2023, 09:51:52node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 17 }
12.7.2023, 09:51:53node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 17 }
12.7.2023, 09:51:54node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 17 }
12.7.2023, 09:51:55node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 17 }
12.7.2023, 09:51:56node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 17 }
12.7.2023, 09:51:57node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 17 }
12.7.2023, 09:51:58node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 33 }
12.7.2023, 09:51:59node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 33 }
12.7.2023, 09:52:00node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 33 }
12.7.2023, 09:52:01node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 33 }
12.7.2023, 09:52:02node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 33 }
12.7.2023, 09:52:03node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 33 }
12.7.2023, 09:52:04node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 33 }
12.7.2023, 09:52:06node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 33 }
12.7.2023, 09:52:07node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 33 }
12.7.2023, 09:52:08node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 33 }
12.7.2023, 09:52:09node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 33 }
12.7.2023, 09:53:19node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val1: "{"val1":1}" }
12.7.2023, 09:53:20node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val1: "{"val1":1}" }
12.7.2023, 09:53:21node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val1: "{"val1":1}" }
```

So the value of the button arrived 3 times perfect but the value of the slider multiple times.

So here the other way.

```
 // Publish to the topics continuouslya
  void _publishMessageContinuous(String topic, Map<String, dynamic> message1) {
    final MqttClientPayloadBuilder builderone = MqttClientPayloadBuilder();
    builderone.addString(jsonEncode(message1));

    final String payload = jsonEncode(message1);
    if (payload != _previousPayload) {
    client.publishMessage(topic, MqttQos.atLeastOnce, builderone.payload!);
    _previousPayload = payload;
    print('Published message: $message1');
    }
  }

  // Publish to the topics discretely
  void _publishMessageDiscrete(String topic, Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    final MqttClientPayloadBuilder builder = MqttClientPayloadBuilder();
    builder.addString(jsonEncode(message));
    client.publishMessage(topic, MqttQos.atLeastOnce, builder.payload!);
    print('Published message: $message');
  }
```

If I'm using the If block, same use the slider and press the button 3 times:

Flutter Debug

```
Restarted application in 2’961ms.
I/flutter (32304): Connected to the MQTT broker
I/flutter (32304): Successfully subscribed to topic mts/canopy/test
I/flutter (32304): Successfully subscribed to topic mts/canopy/gaga
I/flutter (32304): Successfully subscribed to topic mts/canopy/main/canopy
I/flutter (32304): Successfully subscribed to topic mts/canopy/main/cb
I/flutter (32304): Successfully subscribed to topic mts/canopy/main/kitchenside
I/flutter (32304): Successfully subscribed to topic mts/canopy/main/storage
I/ViewRootImpl@c2823db[MainActivity](32304): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/flutter (32304): Published message: {val2: 0}
I/flutter (32304): Published message: {val2: 17}
I/flutter (32304): Published message: {val2: 33}
I/flutter (32304): Published message: {val2: 50}
I/ViewRootImpl@c2823db[MainActivity](32304): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/ViewRootImpl@c2823db[MainActivity](32304): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@c2823db[MainActivity](32304): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/flutter (32304): Published message: {val1: {"val1":1}}
I/ViewRootImpl@c2823db[MainActivity](32304): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@c2823db[MainActivity](32304): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/ViewRootImpl@c2823db[MainActivity](32304): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@c2823db[MainActivity](32304): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/ViewRootImpl@c2823db[MainActivity](32304): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@c2823db[MainActivity](32304): ViewPostIme pointer 1
```

And Node Red:

```
dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 0 }
12.7.2023, 09:56:09node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 17 }
12.7.2023, 09:56:10node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 33 }
12.7.2023, 09:56:11node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val2: 50 }
12.7.2023, 09:56:12node: debug 13dimmersoeze : msg.payload : Object
{ val1: "{"val1":1}"
```

So dimmer value perfect but button only once...

Could anyone help me with that?

If you need more code parts or Information let me know.

Cheers
Oli

What I have try separating the funktions of the button and slider.